# Calling Function in Python Spyder for a UI

Tags: python, user-interface, spyder

> My code will accept values from a User Interface that will then calculate the Density, However when I try and call my function "Properties" It tells me that Pressure2 is undefined. Sorry if my formatting is bad this is my first post.

```
`def variables(self): #This Function gets the initial conditions from the UI
    pressure1=self.ui.pressure1.value
    pressure2=self.ui.pressure2.value
    temp1=self.ui.temp1.value
    temp2=self.ui.temp2.value
    `

def properties(self): #This Function pulls values from array, when user picks the gas. 
    if self.ui.gas_2.findText('Oxygen'):
        rc=elementsMap['Oxygen'][1]
        gamma=elementsMap['Oxygen'][0]
    elif self.ui.gas_2.findText('Helium'):
         rc=elementsMap['Helium'][1]
         gamma=elementsMap['Helium'][0]
    elif self.ui.gas_2.findText('Hydrogen'):
         rc=elementsMap['Hydrogen'][1]
         gamma=elementsMap['Hydrogen'][0]
    def instanous(self): # This function calculates the instanous density.  


    rho2=self.variables(pressure2)/(self.properties(rc)*self.variables(temp2))
     NameError: name 'pressure2' is not defined
```

`

Comment: The answer is right above your error..

Comment: The error happens on the last line of code. "rho2" Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: That's the answer. You put pressure2 where it is undefined. Besides that, your code makes no sense in terms of scope. You should consider looking over some tutorials or MOOC before carrying on.

Comment: Thank You, for the advice.... This is my first semester using Python so it's a little new to me.  So would the solution to my problem by to make pressure2 a Global variable?

Comment: Better avoid global variable unless you have a technical reason to use it, like sharing memory between threads or caching preloaded image of objects. I can write you something later tonight, but now you should think more about how you are using your properties outside your class.

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes in your code:

1. Your code needs to be inside a class definition, because you are referencing `self`.
2. The `self` already have the properties you want, so there is no need to copy the properties in `self` to `self`. For example, when you need pressure2, you can get it from `self.ui.pressure2.value` directly.
3. From what I see, you don't need an object. You need a `tuple`.